# How to generate employee Id?

Tags: java, oop

So I'm creating an employee payroll system and the id requirements are:

1. must always be 10 characters long. The first seven are First 3 letters of first name, the middle initial(default is zero if no middlename), and the first 3 letters of last name
2. the last 3 chars are an incrementing value which represents the number of occurrences of the first 7 characters (eg. AAABCCC001, AAABCCC002, XXXYZZZ001,XXX0ZZZ001 etc).

I'm not sure how to approach this. Help Please!

This is the code I have so far:

```
    count=1;
    fnameSubstr= fname.substring(0,3).toUpperCase();
    mInitial= mnames.substring(0,0).toUpperCase();
    lnameSubstr= lname.substring(0,3).toUpperCase();

    nameStr=fnameSubstr + mInitial + lnameSubstr + String.valueOf(count).format("%03d", count);

    for (Employee e: emp_list){
        if nameStr.equals(id){
            intStr=nameStr.substring(7); //string representing the first 7 chars
            strInt=Integer.parseInt(intStr);//string of the last 3 chars
            if count==strInt{ //compares the count to the int value of the last 3 chars
                count++;
                nameStr=fnameSub + mInitial + lnameSub+String.valueOf(count).format("%03d",count);
            }
         }
         else{
             count=1;
             nameStr=fnameSub + mInitial + lnameSub + String.valueOf(count).format("%03d", count);
         }


     }
```

I'm not sure if I'm on the right track.

Comment: I am sure: you do not approach asking a question here like this. Turn to the [help] to understand how/what to ask here. Hint: we are not a free coding service.

Comment: Please remove the hold for these question because the question asked is proper

Comment: Can someone please tell me how this is too broad? I added my code so you can see what I've attempted so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the below code

`

```
static Integer count = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println(getEmployeeIdBy("DILIP","","DURAISWAMY"));
    System.out.println(getEmployeeIdBy("KUTTY","","DILIP"));
    System.out.println(getEmployeeIdBy("PANDA","R","SADASIBA"));

}

public static String getEmployeeIdBy(String firstName, String middleName, String lastName) {

    String res1 = firstName.substring(0, 3);
    String res2 = middleName.isEmpty() ? "0" : middleName.substring(0, 1);
    String res3 = lastName.substring(0, 3);
    String res4 = res1 + res2 + res3;
    String res5 = count.toString().length() == 1 ? ("00" + count)
            : count.toString().length() == 2 ? ("0" + count) : count.toString();
    count = count + 1;
    String finalResult = res4 + res5;
    return finalResult;

}`
```

The final output would be

```
DIL0DUR000
KUT0DIL001
PANRSAD002
```

Comment: thanks. This is similar to the code I have. The id however is only incrementing if the first 7 characters are the same, and not for each new id. So you have it here as "res4", so count only increments if you search through the list of employees and find that res4 matches the first 7 characters of an existing id. eg, if someone's id is DDDASSS001, and you have another id that starts with DDDASSS, then count would increment to 002, but if another unique id is created, it would go back to 001 , eg, GGGNAAA001. That's the part I'm having the real issue with.

Comment: Ru using database?

Comment: then can you random number generation logic in java?

Comment: actually the above which i have given it will work please try and check

Comment: Below Mentioned answer by user john is also same http://stackoverflow.com/a/43200730/7751463  So please try abd check once

Comment: Thanks alot. I got it to work. You've been very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

1. Get the letters of the from the name using `substring` method. set variables

   ```
   String fName = //first three letters of the first name;
   String mName = "0";
   String lName = //first three letters of the last name;
   if (/*mName is not null*/){
       mName = //get the middle initial
   }
   ```
2. create a `counter = 1` to count how many ids you have made. Note that you can use `String.format("%03d",counter)` to format the counter in three digits; and lastly concatinate all your variables.